# How to install the TRIM RAID update for the Intel storage controller?

Tags: ssd, raid, trim

I just found [this](http://www.bit-tech.net/news/hardware/2010/03/23/intel-releases-trim-for-raid/1) article, that says that Intel now supports TRIM for SSDs when the Intel storage controller is in RAID mode. It links to [this](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/detail_desc.aspx?agr=N&ProductID=&DwnldID=15251) download page. I'm pretty excited about that, but I'm a little confused. There seem to be two sets of drivers, an executable and something that's bootable. I ran the executable. Is that just to apply the drivers to my system now, and are the bootable drivers so that if I re-format, I won't have to re-run everything? Do I need to do both? And is there a way to check if it worked?

I'm running an i7 in Windows 7 (ASUS P6T Deluxe Motherboard) with RAID 0, if that's significant.

Comment: Note that this update only passes the TRIM instruction to *non-RAID* SSDs, when the controller is in RAID mode (see http://www.tech-report.net/discussions.x/18653). So if your X25-M's are in RAID-0, then this update will not allow them to use TRIM; a future update hopefully will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "F6" drivers are only necessary during the installation of Windows, and they were only necessary for versions of Windows earlier than Win 7.  In previous versions of Windows, there was no built-in AHCI or Intel Matrix RAID / RST driver, so you had to hit the F6 key and load suitable drivers from a floppy in order to proceed.  So you don't need those.

The .exe file is the installer for the drivers you want.  I assume that if you have RAID 0 set up and your system is working, that your BIOS was set to RAID (not IDE or AHCI) when you installed Windows.  If you change that setting after Windows is installed, you either have to reinstall Windows or change some registry settings before changing the BIOS.

Finally, sblair's comment is correct, the TRIM passthrough only works for SSDs that are not actually part of the RAID.  For example, if you had a boot SSD, plus a separate RAID 1 or RAID 0 pair of mechanical hard drives, TRIM would work on the SSD.  If it's a pair of SSDs that you have in RAID 0, TRIM still won't work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it comes in two parts:  The first is the installer for the update, the second contains the update itself.